# Core Java-collection framework

Tags: collections

If we are going to add an element in set, where already 2000 of elements are added in the Set and how it will search fastly for the newly adding element is already present in set or not?

Comment: Which `Set` implementation are you using?

Comment: You could use SortedSet (eg TreeSet)

Comment: HashSet implementation

Comment: A Set is a Collection that cannot contain duplicate elements. It has a sorting mechanism.

If you have 2000 elements and want to search fast, you can use sorted sets or tree sets.

TreeSet puts the element in natural ordering or by the provided comparator.

A sortedSet is also keeps the element in natural order.

Answer (score 0):

If you have thousands of elements in your set and you want better performance than you can use HashSet for the operations like add, remove and contains.

HashSet is fastest, LinkedHashSet is second on performance or almost similar to HashSet but TreeSet is bit slower because of sorting operation it needs to perform on each insertion.

HashSet and LinkedHashSet offers constant time cost e.g. O(1) while TreeSet offers log(n) time cost for such operations. HashSet does not maintain any order while LinkedHashSet maintains insertion order of elements.